# Should you deploy 32 or 64-bit SQL Server Express with your application?

Tags: sql-server, deployment, 32bit-64bit

So far, we only deployed 32-bit SQL Server Express with our application, since it runs on 32 and 64 bit operating systems.

Is there a compelling reason (i.e., a reason that's worth the additional file size and the additional complexity in the setup routine) to add 64-bit SQL Server Express as another option?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to use a 64-bit SQL Server, unless you intend hosting a large database - hence consuming large amounts of memory or large files.

The only reason I'd see for providing a 64-bit SQL Server express, is if your customer (end user) would prefer that for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you think enough users would make use of the 64Bit version I would do a trial and compare results of the application running 64Bit and 32Bit versions of SQL. If there is a performance bonus I would say go for it. Generally though if everything you do can be done comfortably in 1-2gb of ram and you never need more then 64Bit wont really do much for you.

With a 64 bit option your database would gain increased performance if you have a high number of concurrent users. You will gain all the advantages of 64Bit hardware such as the ability to handle larger files, to make use of larger memory / more CPUs etc. This may not be applicable to your application though.

Im not sure what your competitors do but Another completely non performance related reason to offer 64bit is if you can say your application supports both 32bit and 64bit it may be a boost to sales and help you stand out from the crowd. If you get ill informed people aproving the software purchase (as is often the case) they often make decisions without all the facts "look this one is 64bit, this one is only 32bit" etc. Also if a company has just invested in a 64bit OS / new 64bit hardware they want to make use of that investment and will gravitate towards applications that will use 64bit regardless of if it is needed.